# Load jquery library and custom code using requirejs

Tags: jquery, symfony, requirejs

I'm working on a project that uses `requirejs` to manage the `javascript` files.

Let's say I have `src/resource/template/doc.html.twig` and I want to link it the `web/assets/js/lib/export/doc.js` and `jquery library`.
We have the `requirejs.js` file with this inside:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery':'../vendor/jquery/jquery',
```

and I added this trying to link `jquery` to the file, but it didn't work:

```
shim: {
'lib/export/doc': {
          deps: ['jquery']
        },
```

I know my question is not very specific, but I have no idea what I'm doing here; I'd appreciate any kind of guidance.

Comment: I don't this this path is correct `../vendor/jquery/jquery`. Try this `vendor/jquery/jquery` out. I also suggest you using this guide: http://www.nicolasbottarini.com/using-requirejs-for-symfony-2-development/

Comment: Could you paste the entire config used for require? Also the define part of a module where `'jquery'` is required. Third what version of require is being used.